# Can I pass a class or interface type as a parameter to a function

Tags: typescript

Can I pass a class or interface type as a parameter to a function?
In addition, how can I tell if a class or interface declares a property?
The hasOwnPropery method is used to instantiate an object and does not meet my needs.

I want to create a function limitdAssign.but I don't know how to do.

```
interface IStudent {
  name: string;
}

interface ISeniorStudent {
  name: string;
  height: number;
}

 it('type cast ', () => {
    const seniorStudent: ISeniorStudent = { name: 'alan', height: 177 };
    console.log('Class: , Function: , Line 18 (): ', JSON.stringify(seniorStudent));
 // {"name":"alan","height":177}
    const stu = { ...seniorStudent } as IStudent;
    console.log('Class: , Function: , Line 21 (): ', JSON.stringify(limitedAssign(seniorStudent))); 
// {"name":"alan"}
  });
```

Comment: 1. of course. Otherwise, those would be pretty useless. Why don't you just try it? 2. No, hasOwnProperty isn't used to instantiate an object. Here's its documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty. I'm not sure what you want to achieve exactly. A concrete problem description and a code example would help.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple parts to your question:

1. An interface *type* cannot be passed as a parameter. When running TypeScript code, you are really compiling it down to JavaScript and then running the JavaScript. An interface is a TypeScript compile-time construct, so at runtime, there is no such thing as an interface type to call functions on or inspect properties of. However, they can still be used at compile-time, like to define parameter types, return types, and for use in [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in these definitions.
2. Classes as they are traditionally thought about in strongly typed languages do not exist in JavaScript. The JavaScript `class` keyword just declares a [special type of function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Therefore, operations that reflect on the definitions of "classes" and "interfaces" don't exist. The closest you can get is to inspect objects at runtime with functions such as `hasOwnProperty` or operators like [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) and [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

Check out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) for a more detailed explanation of JavaScript's prototypical inheritance system.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that generates the Javascript code as a string which is a macro (code that generates code) , and then call that string with the Javascript keyword eval.

### NOTE:

It's worth undertsanding the dnagers of using `eval`, see [MDN's warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)
Most notably:

> `eval()` executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run `eval()` with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, allowing third-party code to access the scope in which `eval()` was invoked (if it's a direct eval) can lead to possible attacks that reads or changes local variables.